# GetLocaleInfo prevents my application from exiting

Tags: windows, delphi, localization, locale

Here is the code I had used to detect default system language:

```
var
  Buffer    : PChar;
  Size      : integer;
  LocaleName: String;
begin
  Size := GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, nil, 0);
  GetMem(Buffer, Size);
  try
    GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, Buffer, Size);
    LocaleName := string(Buffer);
  finally
    FreeMem(Buffer);
  end;
  ShowMessage(LocaleName);
end;
```

This code works great, alas for as long as the code is there my application will not quit until I use the Task Manager to stop it. Finally I found this little code that also does the trick and allow my application to quit:

```
Var
 MyLang: PChar
 LocaleName: string;
 Ident: integer;
begin
  GetMem(MyLang, 250);
  try
    Ident:=GetSystemDefaultLangID;
    VerLanguageName(Ident, MyLang, 250);
    LocaleName := StrPas(MyLang);
  Finally
    FreeMem(MyLang);
  end;
  ShowMessage(LocaleName);
end;
```

Can anyone guess the reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

Second call to GetLocaleInfo overwrites memory, because GetLocaleInfo returns number of chars, and you are using unicode version of Delphi, then you need allocate 2 bytes per char.

You can fix it by: GetMem(Buffer, Size * SizeOf(Char)); // SizeOf(Char)==SizeOf(WideChar) on >= D2009